# Too many Mesh and Verticals

Tags: modeling

i'm new to Blender so this might be a very dumb question... Still learning! So i made this frog with a tutorial on YT but the woman said to delete the modifiers after saving them but now i'm stuck with WAY to many lines... How do I undo this??[image]

Comment: You should always keep a version with unapplied Subdivision Surface modifier. That said, you can try some things like select all and Ctrl E > Un-Subdivide

Comment: Thank you so much it worked!!

Comment: Blender creates a backup of the last save. It's called *.blend1. Maybe you're lucky and can restore a version before you applied the modifier? It also saves every 5 min the file in the temp folder. You can restore it with *File > Recover > Auto Save ....*

Answer (score 1):

You should always keep a version with unapplied *Subdivision Surface* modifier. That said, you can try some things like select all in *Edit* mode and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > *Un-Subdivide* (and tweak the parameters in the *Operator* box).